# Unable to locate cc_args.py on my computer

Tags: python, c++, go

I am trying to download the gocode package for golang, and it is trying to use a cc_args.py file. However, it doesn't seem like I have it, and I am unsure how to obtain it.

It seems like this is a file used a lot in c++ and c compiling which I have done before, so I am not sure why it's gone now.

This is what my console looks like

```
go get -v github.com/mdempsky/gocode
runtime/cgo
# runtime/cgo
fork/exec ../cc_args.py: no such file or directory
```

EDIT: So my issue was indeed my PATH variable.

Comment: Have you had the chance to look at the [setup](https://github.com/mdempsky/gocode#setup) section in the readme?

Comment: @Abdullah I tried updating my path variables using that guide but still gives me the issue